# Android - Permission denied when binding a mobile network socket (OkHttp.socketFactory(network.socketFactory))

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm looking for your help / ideas related to the problem below:

**What I want to achieve:**

- route requests through mobile network on Android, using Retrofit2, OktHttp

**What I did:**

- obtained the needed *Network* instance using *ConnectivityManager*
- set the *socketFactory* for *OkHttpClient* to use the one from the *Network* instance
- specified these permissions in *AndroidManifest.xml*.:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**Example code:**

```
val network: Network = connectivityManager.allNetworks.first {
    connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(it)?.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) == true
}

val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .socketFactory(network.socketFactory)
            .build()
```

**Result:**

- exception is thrown: *java.net.SocketException: Binding socket to network 505 failed: EACCES (Permission denied)*

**Notes / Disclaimer:**

- the above works for WiFi
- I know this is a bad practice: it is **not** the default behaviour of the application. Users can opt-in and opt-out anytime. There's a specific use case in which this makes sense.

If you have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong, or why isn't it working for mobile networks, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find out why I did wrong.

**In a nutshell:**

- instead of *ConnectivityManager.getAllNetworks()* use *ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork()*, specifying the network details and use the received one.

```
val cellularRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
    .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
    .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
    .build()

connectivityManager.requestNetwork(cellularRequest, object :
            ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                // use the network...
            }
        })
```

**The long story:**
When testing, I had WiFi and Mobile Data turned on.
From the docs about *ConnectivityManager.getAllNetworks()*:

- *"Returns an array of all Network **currently tracked** by the framework."*
- I think the keyword here is the part I've highlighted (Mobile data network interface will not be tracked from the start, it won't appear in the list. When I've seen the one with CELLULAR capabilities, I thought that's the one I'm looking for. I was mistaken. That's a different interface. I didn't observe that it has no internet capability.)
- by default, it returned 2 network instances, see below:

| Network ID | Capabilities |
| --- | --- |
| 525 | Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: **IMS**&NOT_METERED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED |
| 767 | Transports: WIFI Capabilities: NOT_METERED&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED |

Notice, that the CELLULAR one (ID: 525) has no internet capabilities, and has IMS (which, if I understood correctly from the docs, refers to the GSM network).
When I've tried to bind the socket to this network, it obviously failed.
I've then called the *requestNetwork()* method, and observed that I've received a new (3rd) network instance:

| Network ID | Capabilities |
| --- | --- |
| 770 | Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&**INTERNET**&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&VALIDATED&NOT_ROAMING&FOREGROUND&NOT_CONGESTED&NOT_SUSPENDED |

Using this one, the binding works seamlessly.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar with you, however I am not able to achieve my approach. Even if I call requestNetwork and I set this network's socket factory into OkHttp builder instance, it does not work. Is your code working ok? Anything to advise?

Comment: On the OkHttp builder the DNS must also be set.

class NetworkBoundDns(private val network: Network): Dns {
        override fun lookup(hostname: String): List<InetAddress> {
            val inetAddresses = network.getAllByName(hostname)
            return inetAddresses.toList()
        }
    }

and in the builder instance use it like:

.dns(NetworkBoundDns(network))
.socketFactory(network.socketFactory)

Comment: Can you please help me how to pass onAvailable network in socketFactory in OkHttpClient

Comment: I'd suggest you to use requestNetwork from ConnectivityManager. Passing the network instance from onAvailable would mean always recreating OkHttp instances. Please see the code on my comment above, I've written an example on how to set the socketFactory. I hope it helps. Let me know if I can help more.